# puppet kick without polling?

Tags: puppet

I'm using Puppet in **kick**-mode (puppetrun):

Client's puppet.conf:

```
[main]
    modulepath = /etc/puppet/modules:/usr/share/puppet/modules
    logdir = /var/log/puppet
    rundir = /var/run/puppet

    # The default value is '$confdir/ssl'.
    ssldir = $vardir/ssl
    server = puppetmaster.example.com
    listen = true

    # only kick, no polling
    client = false
    certname = client.example.com
    pluginsync = true

[agent]
    # The default value is '$confdir/classes.txt'.
    classfile = $vardir/classes.txt
    ignorecache = true
    report = true
    environment = dev
    client = false

    # The default value is '/localconfig'.
    localconfig = $vardir/localconfig
```

**puppet kick --host ** works great, but additionally every 30 (runinterval) minutes the puppet client does a deployment triggered by itself (polling).

I thought **client=false** stops the polling, but it seems like it doesn't.

Does anybody know a way to solve this?

Thanks from Munich,
Andi

Comment: probably needs to be on serverfault.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the `client = false` directive in puppet.conf does not exist , according to
http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/stable/configuration.html (although the top of the
page specifies it should be available).

There is however the `--no-client` option you can specify when starting the agent (check with `puppet help agent`):

```
--no-client:
  Do not create a config client. This will cause the daemon to run
  without ever checking for its configuration automatically, and only
  makes sense when puppet agent is being run with listen = true in puppet.conf
  or was started with the `--listen` option.
```

The best place to add these is in `/etc/sysconfig/puppet` for RPM based GNU/Linux distributions, and `/etc/default/puppet` for deb based ones.
For others, you'll have to check the start scripts.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want 'onetime=true' in the [main] section.  It doesn't look like there's a client setting.  See http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/stable/configuration.html#onetime

Comment: No, the Daemon should run on the Client, but i want to push from the puppetmaster and not pull from the client.